# Updating field with Active Admin Batch Action (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm trying to update the field "validated" with the value true (if the "Ad" - the model - is selected).

I've tried to find an answer in the documentation, however its difficult to see how to update a field (the documentation talks about removal and flagging). Any help would be appreciated.

Current code (not working):

```
    batch_action :validated do |selection|
    Ad.find(selection).each do |ad|
      ad.validated => true
    end
  end
```

Thanks!

Comment: ad.update(validated: true)   or I am guess selection is a condition not a id...Ad.where(selection).update_all(validated: true)

Comment: I usually do this. `batch_action "Update 'Status' ", form: { active: [['Active',1],['Inactive',0]] } do |ids, inputs|
    User.where(id: ids).update_all(active: inputs[:active])
    redirect_to collection_path, notice: "Status updated successfully"
  end`

Comment: @sethi - thanks, I just added in: ad.update(validated: true) and it worked! Just need to sort out the redirection and I'm good to go.

Comment: @sajan Any clues with redirection back to the previous page after update?

Comment: You mean reload the page? redirect_to :back